# large xml sort by akey

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

How to sort a xml like this we would like to sort this with the 'BestAmount' element , this is a part of a very large xml around 900 records , please let us know how we can sort this fast . The xml is retrieved via a soap request

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <HotelSearchResult xmlns="http://www.sson.com/XSD">
         <HotelAvailRS>
            <Success />
            <ResponseData>
               <CheckIn>2013-08-22T00:40:44</CheckIn>
               <CheckOut>2013-08-23T00:40:44</CheckOut>
               <ISOCurrency>USD</ISOCurrency>
               <LocationCode>SG9</LocationCode>
               <HotelAvails>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000140</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Crystal</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>An affordable but comfortable option in the busy Geylang area, the Fragrance Hotel Crystal offers outstanding monetary value for both tourists and bus</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000140.wct</Image>
                     <Address>50</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6844 - 7888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>50.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000142</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Pearl</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>Situated in an exciting part of Singapore that provides a glimpse into the local flavour of the island, this property is an ideal place for those who</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000142.wct</Image>
                     <Address>21 Lorong</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6842 - 7888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>50.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0910100087</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Sunflower</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>Fragrance Chain of Hotels is one of the leading chain of tourist class hotels in Singapore, founded in 1996, it started its debut in hotel management</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0910100087.wct</Image>
                     <Address>10 Lorong 10 Geylang</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6846 - 7888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>50.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000141</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Emerald</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>Catering to international budget travellers, the hotel is designed to uplift your spirit with its Asian inspired decor and enables you to discover its</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000141.wct</Image>
                     <Address>20 Lorong 6 Geylang</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6842 - 3888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>54.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000093</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Joo Chiat</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>The Fragrance Hotel has been specially designed for convenience and comfort and boasts a great location in the Malay-heritage Joo Chiat area and close</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000093.wct</Image>
                     <Address>219</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6344 - 9888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>54.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000166</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Ruby</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>Offering an atmosphere of warmth and comfort to the weary travellers, this property is a second home, while you are on a holiday in the bustle of the</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000166.wct</Image>
                     <Address>10</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6841 - 3888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>54.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel>
                     <Status>Available</Status>
                     <Code>WSMA0511000167</Code>
                     <Name>Fragrance Sapphire</Name>
                     <Rating>2</Rating>
                     <Description>Set against the historical hub of Geylang, Fragrance Hotel Sapphire is a unique harmony of history, tradition and modernity. Fragrance Hotel Sapphire</Description>
                     <Image>http://dxhapi.travelcarma.com/ImgHandler.ashx?p=gc.uvzt.genirypnezn.pbz/GY/JFZN0511000167.wct</Image>
                     <Address>3</Address>
                     <City>Singapore City</City>
                     <Country>Singapore</Country>
                     <Phone>(65) 6841 - 4888</Phone>
                     <BestAmount>54.00</BestAmount>
                     <HotelToken>E4+WDyPLOLGEQ2A4rl5MSyN9PvgddSt25KxIJ3DRg78=</HotelToken>
                  </Hotel>
```

Comment: sort for what? regenerating the xml? pulling out records for processing in order?

Comment: Please remove the SOAP envelope first, it's not needed any longer and only complicates what you ask for. And then you should outline what the expected outcome should be. You find a checklist here to write a proper question here: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/147909)

Comment: Also please provide reference for the webservice SOAP-API you're using. There is good reason to assume that the webservice can already return the result ordered.

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT stylesheet with 2 rules does the job:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:HotelAvails" xmlns:h="http://www.sson.com/XSD">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="h:Hotel">
      <xsl:sort select="h:BestAmount" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

This will run under either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.